# "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00923

I am getting the following error

> "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" while executing the query

```
SELECT 
    count(pf.pref_selection) filter ( WHERE pc.collection = "players")      OVER (partition BY pc.collection,pc.user_id )  AS Avg_players        
    count(pf.pref_selection) filter ( WHERE pc.collection = "teams")        OVER (partition BY pc.collection,pc.user_id )  AS Avg_teams  
FROM NBA_OWNER.PREFERENCES pf 
inner join NBA_OWNER.PREF_COLLECTIONS pc on pc.ID=pf.COLLECTION_ID 
where pc.LAST_UPDATE_DATE>"30-SEP-16'`
```

Comment: Does that formatting help? You have no commas between SELECT columns

Comment: Where did you find that syntax? `filter` and the `where` in the parentheses are not valid. Also seems odd to be using analytic counts here; you'll get lots of rows back, but will have no idea which user ID they relate to. Are you sure you don't want aggregate counts, and to include the user in the select list?

Comment: @AlexPoole: the `filter` clause is actually part of the SQL standard, but Oracle doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors. As @cricket_007 pointed put you are missing a comma between the two count expressions. But you also have invalid syntax with your `filter` clause - which doesn't exist, at least in Oracle; you have used double quotes around string literals instead of single quotes; the quotes around your date string are even odder; and you are relying on NLS settings for the date format.

This is closer to what you need, if I understand what you were attempting:

```
SELECT 
    count(case when pc.collection = 'players' then pf.pref_selection end)
      OVER (partition BY pc.user_id) AS Avg_players, 
    count(case when pc.collection = 'teams' then pf.pref_selection end)
      OVER (partition BY pc.user_id) AS Avg_teams  
FROM NBA_OWNER.PREFERENCES pf 
inner join NBA_OWNER.PREF_COLLECTIONS pc on pc.ID=pf.COLLECTION_ID 
where pc.LAST_UPDATE_DATE > date '2016-09-30'
```

The output might not be very useful though. For each user ID you may get multiple rows, each showing the total count (which you've called `avg` for some reason). You probably only want to see the counts for each ID once, and to see which ID they relate to, so I think you want an aggregate rather than analytic count:

```
SELECT 
    pc.user_id,
    count(case when pc.collection = 'players' then pf.pref_selection end)
      AS Avg_players,      
    count(case when pc.collection = 'teams' then pf.pref_selection end)
      AS Avg_teams  
FROM NBA_OWNER.PREFERENCES pf 
inner join NBA_OWNER.PREF_COLLECTIONS pc on pc.ID=pf.COLLECTION_ID 
where pc.LAST_UPDATE_DATE > date '2016-09-30'
group by pc.user_id
```

Comment: The `filter` clause is indeed standard SQL, but as you pointed out, Oracle does not support it.

Comment: I had a feeling it might be, and that you'd know *8-) Not one I've seen even in passing, from my closeted Oracle world. Thanks.

Comment: To my knowledge it's only Postgres and HSQLDB that support this currently

Comment: Thanks for your reply everyone.Im actually trying to find the average of the number of users who have selected players and average of the users who have selected teams. Do u have any suggestions for me.thank you